# How to get order id of woocommerce in the URL with slash

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Example url:
https://example.com/checkout/order-pay/24463/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_60e277a2e517f

I want to get to order id 24463

Answer (score 2):

Well a regex should do the job, but as you are in a woocommerce environment (tag) and want to get this in php (tag) when you are on this page then there is a much more simpler way to get it.

```php
if(is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' )) {
   $order_id = get_query_var('order-pay');
}
```

You should have the id in `$order_id`.